# Check if variable is a block / function / callable in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a simple and definite way in Swift to check whether something is a callable block / function? In some languages it's a trivial thing, but perhaps I'm looking at this from a wrong perspective in Swift? Consider the following.

```
func foo(){ print("foo") }
var bar: () -> () = { print("bar") }
var baz: () -> (Bool) = { print("baz"); return true }

print(foo) // (Function)
print(bar) // (Function)
print(baz) // (Function)

print(foo is () -> ()) // true
print(bar is () -> ()) // true
print(baz is () -> ()) // false
print(baz is () -> (Bool)) // true
```

Swift knows that they are all functions, though there is no such data type. I can check by using a solid signature, but there might be a situation where I don't care about the signature<sup>*</sup> and simply want to invoke it. For example:

```
func call(callable: () -> ()) {
    callable()
}

call(foo) // foo
call(bar) // bar
call(baz) // error: cannot convert value of type '() -> (Bool)' to expected argument type '() -> ()'
```

I can rewrite it like this, which will work for `Void` and `Bool` return types, but doing this for every type is crazy, especially since I don't care about it, but compiler does…

```
func call(callable: Any) {
    if let block: () -> () = callable as? () -> () {
        block()
    } else if let block: () -> (Bool) = callable as? () -> (Bool) {
        block()
    }
}

call(foo) // foo
call(bar) // bar
call(baz) // truely baz
```

<sup>*</sup> Agree, not caring about the signature is a sin. For the argument sake let's just not care about the return type.

Comment: I guess a problem to consider would be, that you would not only have to know, if the variable was callable, but if it expects parameters. Knowing if something is callable is of no value if you don't know it's parameters.

Comment: True, hence the footnote.

Comment: But I'm not talking about the return type. I'm talking about the parameters.

Comment: Function signature defines all of those, sorry if wasn't clear. You are thinking is completely correct, if we could make a random call if could easily lead to bigger problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the String representation of `.dynamicType` of the callable for existence of substring `->`. Not super-elegant, but it works:

```
func isAClosure<T>(foo: T) -> Bool {
    return String(foo.dynamicType).containsString("->")
}

var a : () -> () = { print("Foobar") }
var b : (Double) -> (Bool) = { $0 > 0 }
var c : Int = 1

isAClosure(a) // true
isAClosure(b) // true
isAClosure(c) // false
```

Of course, as Marcus Rossel points out in the comment above, you still wouldn't know anything about the parameters of the callable (but perhaps that could be next step to find out, given that you know it's a callable).

---

*Addition with regard to OPs questions below: just a technical discussion, and not recommended techniques.*

You use the same approach as above to check if the function argument is a closure without arguments (`() -> (...)`) or one with neither arguments nor return type (`() -> ()`), and so on. Using this approach, you can define a generic function that call the argument sent to the function only if it is of a certain closure type. For this *"in-function-call"*, you'll have to make use of type conversion to expected closure type, much as you've described in your Q above. It'll probably be difficult to circumvent this "non-generic" approach w.r.t. *calling* the closures. A few examples follow below.

```
/* Example functions */
func isAVoidParamClosure<T>(foo: T) -> Bool {
    let bar = String(foo.dynamicType).componentsSeparatedByString(" -> ")
    return bar.count > 1 && (bar.first?.characters.count ?? 0) == 2
}

func callIfVoidVoidClosure<T>(foo: T) {
    let bar = String(foo.dynamicType).componentsSeparatedByString(" -> ")
    if bar.count > 1 && !(bar.map{ $0 == "()" }.contains(false)) {
        if let foo = foo as? () -> () {
            foo()
        }
    }
}

func isASingleDoubleReturnTypeClosure<T>(foo: T) -> Bool {
    let bar = String(foo.dynamicType).componentsSeparatedByString(" -> ")
    return bar.count > 1 && bar[1] == "Double"
        /* rhs of '&&' lazily evaluated: [1] ok */
}

func printTwoTimesResultOfVoidDoubleClosure<T>(foo: T) {
    if isAVoidParamClosure(foo) && isASingleDoubleReturnTypeClosure(foo) {
        if let foo = foo as? () -> Double {
            let a: Double = 2*foo()
            print(a)
        }
    }
}
```

Example calls:

```
/* Example calls */
let a : () -> () = { print("Foobar") }
let b : (Double) -> (Bool) = { $0 > 0 }
let c : () -> Double = { 21.0 }
let d : Int = 1

isAVoidParamClosure(a) // true
isAVoidParamClosure(b) // false
isAVoidParamClosure(c) // true
isAVoidParamClosure(d) // false

callIfVoidVoidClosure(a) // Prints "Foobar"
callIfVoidVoidClosure(b)
callIfVoidVoidClosure(c)
callIfVoidVoidClosure(d)

printTwoTimesResultOfVoidDoubleClosure(a)
printTwoTimesResultOfVoidDoubleClosure(b) // Prints "42.0"
printTwoTimesResultOfVoidDoubleClosure(c)
printTwoTimesResultOfVoidDoubleClosure(d)
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about something like that, it just feels a little hacky, like you mentioned.

Comment: Between, say, hypothetically we found out that we have a closure that takes no parameters. Is there a way to invoke it without knowing the return type? Or do we still have to cast it like in the last example in the question?

Comment: @IanBytchek I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do, but: first of all we don't _have_ to make use of the return type, so for `let b : () -> (Bool) = { return true }` we could just call it and ignore the return type, i.e. `b()`. However, if you are referring to calling `foo` within the function above (if _we_ know it's a closure), would be trickier: the compiler knows nothin about the type of `foo` (even if we do). Also, since closures are non-nominal types, we can't use the possibly alternative approach where we type constraint some function to only take zero-parameter closures.

Comment: just a tiny bit shorter than `foo.dynamicType` would be `T.self`.

Comment: @IanBytchek I added a discussion above, regarding what I think you inquired about in your last comment.

Comment: Even if in practice one ignores a return value, in order for Swift to call a function/closure it has to have *static* knowledge of the parameter and return types. Hence, as noted several times in comments and in this answer, there's little value to *dynamic* introspection of whether a value is a "callable type". (Or even to dynamic introspection of type signatures, because you can't dynamically make use of them.)

Comment: That was enlightening. Basically it all comes down to plain string manipulation and lots of conditionals, which isn't very neat, but a possible approach. That was the thesis @rickster, though being able to match `()->Bool` or `()->String` to `()->Any` would be useful and nice to have.