# Enumerating swift method parameter names and values

Tags: ios, swift, methods, parameters

I am looking for a way to enumerate swift method parameters, without explicitly naming them.

To be specific, I want to log all parameters in an arbitrary closure - preferably with both name and value. It would also be nice to have access to other meta-information about the current closure: name of method if any, return type, ...

Are there any ways to access this information?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't really make any practical use of runtime introspection on methods or closures (no children to enumerate over); at best you can get the type of the parameters (as well as return type) of the function/closure by manual string operations on `String(foo.dynamicType)`, where `foo` is a function of a closure. Related: [see the following Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35046837/4573247), specifically user rickster:s comment to the answer.

Comment: Thanks!
Per the Rickster comment - "in order for Swift to call a function/closure it has to have static knowledge of the parameter and return types” - well, the static knowledge is what I am after… Too bad it is not readily available…